# Android MapView not reloading while zooming

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

I'm using my own MapView, that derives from MapView in a Fragment. When I zoom out using the zoom out gesture it shows white space around the small piece of zoomed out map. Then, when I release my fingers from the touch screen it reloads the map. I tried `invalidate()` in onTouchEvent() but nothing happens. Do you know how to fix this?